# Is there any public API for Discord Rich Presence independant of the official client?

Tags: discord

I'm working on a UWP app with a feature where other apps could set Discord Rich Presence via an AppServiceConnection. However on most UWP platforms forwarding from the AppServiceConnection to the Offical Client is not an available option. I'm looking to set the Rich Presence directly from the app essentially. Despite a ton of digging through network packets I'm still entirely lost. Anyone know of documentation on it or has some super method to sniff these packets out (Fiddler 4, Netmon and Wireshark aren't cutting it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more Reverse Engineering, the Rich Presence is sent via the Gateway with op code 3 and the Game object, Minimum args Name and Type and a far more complex object you can find in https://github.com/Avid29/QuarrelRichPresence/blob/master/Objects.cs

Answer (score 1):

The only possible ways to set a rich presence are documented in the official SDK which uses IPC for setting the presence. [sdk on github](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-rpc) [official documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/rich-presence/how-to)

As you can see on github, some people have already written libraries for other languages based on the official SDK: [wrappers and implementations](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-rpc#wrappers-and-implementations).